# Is there a keyboard shortcut for hiding the suggestion bar?

Tags: interface

I see that there's a control I can click to hide or "minimize" version 9.0's "suggestion bar". Is there a keyboard shortcut to do this?

Comment: Actually I was just wondering if there is a shortcut to force *show* it, in particular after a cell that lost it's output property (think changing the layout of a graph using the context menu).

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes: something to *toggle* it would be great. A surprising omission.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the summary:

- There is no shortcut (you can [suggest here](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback))
- Quick close/open labeled **minimize** below

  [image]
- Disable from Top **Menu >> Edit >> Preferences...**

  [image]

Comment: I don't want to disable. Just toggle. Are there UI/UX folks on staff at Wolfram?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I know you don't - I just gave a complete summary for you and anyone else who reads this post. I also gave you the official root to suggest your concerns.

Comment: This setting doesn't just collapse it by default, it gets rid of the control to expand it altogether. Can that be right?

Answer (score 3):

[The *Mathematica* documentation on keyboard shortcuts](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html)
shows no shortcut for the hiding the suggestion bar

Comment: That's why I asked: seems incredible that you can't toggle something designed make interaction convenient with something convenient.

Comment: Also, absence of information in the documentation means little, considering the state of Mathematica's docs.

Answer (score 1):

As already said by everyone else, there isn't a keyboard shortcut I'm aware of and don't currently know how to assign one.

But, I use the following when showing people the interface

```
Column[{Button["Predictive Interface Off", dummy1 = 2; SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
ShowPredictiveInterface -> False], Appearance -> Dynamic[If[dummy1 === 2, "Pressed", 
Automatic]]], Button["Predictive Interface On", dummy1 = 1; 
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowPredictiveInterface -> True], Appearance -> 
Dynamic[If[dummy1 === 1, "Pressed", Automatic]]]}]
```

And because I need to practice programmatically building things, here's some code to put that into a palette (you'll need to restart *Mathematica* afterwards, and I couldn't quite get the `Appearance` option to be fully dynamic w.r.t to `ShowPredictiveInterface`)

```
NotebookSave[
CreateDocument[{ExpressionCell[
Column[{Button["Suggestions Off", dummy1 = 2; 
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, ShowPredictiveInterface -> False],
    Appearance -> 
    Dynamic[If[dummy1 === 2, "Pressed", Automatic]]], 
    Button["Suggestions On", dummy1 = 1; 
    SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, ShowPredictiveInterface -> True],
Appearance -> Dynamic[If[dummy1 === 1, "Pressed", Automatic]]]}]]}, WindowSize -> All,      
ShowCellBracket -> False, 
WindowElements -> {}, WindowFrame -> "FramedPalette", 
Selectable -> "False", Editable -> "False", Saveable -> "False", 
PaneBoxOptions -> {Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit"}, 
StyleDefinitions -> "SystemPalette.nb", 
WindowTitle -> "Suggestions?"], 
FileNameJoin[{CreateDirectory[
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", 
"SuggestionsBar", "FrontEnd", "Palettes"}]], 
"Suggestions-Palette.nb"}]]
```

Comment: Note that with the new `CellObjects` you should be able to control this cell by cell.